# Netty 4.1: DefaultEventExecutorGroup.maxPendingTasks, per EventExecutor or group?

Tags: netty

Looking at the javadoc for DefaultEventExecutorGroup, I would expect the parameter "maxPendingTasks" to mean the max number of pending tasks that are allowed in total for the whole group of EventExecutors. However, when looking at the code it seems that "maxPendingTasks" is per EventExecutor. So a group with 20 EventExecutors could have 20 * maxPendingTasks tasks pending.

Is this the intended behaviour? (If so, it might be a good idea to update the documentation for DefaultEventExecutorGroup to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its the intended behaviour.... That said PRs are welcome to clarify this :)